# php mysqli connect to old version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two versions of MySQL, 5.6.20 and 5.7.25, installed on my server.

My `php.ini` has

```
; php.ini
mysqli.default_socket=/opt/local/var/run/mysql57/mysqld.sock
```

I can edit tables for 5.7.25 using `phpMyAdmin`, after which I see the updated records correctly (when using `mysql` or `phpMyAdmin`) for 5.7.25.

But when I put the following codes in a php file, I get version number 5.6.20:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", USERNAME, PASSWORD, "testdb");
echo mysqli_get_server_version($link);       # shows 50620
```

What would be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `127.0.0.1` isn't actually the same as `localhost` to MySQL.  When you pass an IP address in the `$host` parameter, the connection is forced over TCP/IP.  Instead, pass `"localhost"` and it should use the default UNIX socket instead of the network socket.  (When using a default socket, I actually prefer to pass `NULL`—which gets converted to `localhost`—just to make it clearer that I'm expecting the connection to happen via socket.)

---

**If that still isn't working, here are some troubleshooting steps you can take:**

1. Place a `phpinfo()` file and look under the MySQLi section with specific attention to the values of `MYSQLI_SOCKET` and `mysqli.default_socket` (both local and master values).  It's possible that either this value is being overridden somewhere.  If you see a different value in `MYSQLI_SOCKET`, it's likely being influenced by the `--with-mysqli-sock` compile-time flag.
2. You could run is echoing the output of `mysqli_get_host_info($link)` (just to see if it's connecting via TCP or the socket).
3. You could also test by manually passing the correct socket in the 6th parameter (`$socket`) of `mysqli_connect()`. Again, this needs to be combined with the use of `NULL`/`localhost` for the `$host` argument.